# How to count records from two different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables students and payments. 
The payment table stores records of student fee payment. How do I get the total number of students who have not paid schools fees for a selected session? for example session: 2017/2018

I used the following code and I took more than 10 seconds to give result.

```sql
SELECT   Count(students.registrationno)
FROM     students
WHERE    registrationno NOT IN
         (
          SELECT   DISTINCT payments.reg_no
          FROM payments
          WHERE payments.`session`='2017/2018'
         )
```

```
students
+----------------+------------+--------------+
| registrationno |   surname  |     firstname|
|----------------+------------+--------------|
| 100009         |   OGBODO   |     IPU      |
| 100014         |   IKE      |     JOSEPH   |
| 100033         |   JOHN     |     AJENE    |
+----------------+------------+--------------+

payments

+-------------+---------+-----------+ 
| payment_id  |  reg_no |   session |
|-------------+---------+-----------+
| 1           |  100009 | 2017/2018 |
| 2           |  180689 | 2017/2018 |
| 3           |  180680 | 2017/2018 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

```sql
SELECT  COUNT(students.registrationno)
FROM    students
WHERE   registrationno NOT IN 
       (
        SELECT   DISTINCT payments.reg_no
        FROM     payments
        WHERE    payments.`session`='2017/2018'
       )
```

I expect the output in less than 10 seconds

Comment: Add indexes on your tables.

Comment: @SalmanA Which table do I add the indexes and which columns?

Comment: I would try `students (registrationno)` and `payments (session, reg_no)`

Answer (score 0):

Use joins

```
SELECT count(*) FROM students st
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM payments WHERE session='2017/2018') pmt 
ON st.registrationno = pmt.reg_no WHERE pmt.reg_no IS NULL;
```

The condition `pmt.reg_no is null` ensures that the query will return
the student records with no payment entry in the corresponding session.

Also create appropriate indexes(eg. students.registrationno) 
for significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in the comment, adding `indexes` could help you to increase the performance.

Below is one of alternative method which you could try but I believe it will be less efficient than `NOT IN`

```
SELECT  count(s.registrationno)
FROM    students s
LEFT JOIN
        payments p
ON      p.reg_no  = s.registrationno
WHERE   p.reg_no IS NULL
AND P.session='2017/2018'
```

You can also try `NOT EXISTS`